# Mongoose "query.save()" doesn't update boolean value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, boolean

I'm trying to create an JSON-api to manage  todos. When user creates an document using post request, server returns an **token** and the created document's **id**
This project uses **mongodb** to save data, and **mongoose** to make the requests.

this is a test application, and i want to practice myself using encryption in document's **name**, **the todos**, **token**.

Now i am in situation where there is an **options**, and i need to save **protectedWithToken** value in settings object.
It didn't seem to work, so i added couple of *console.log()* functions.

This is the schema of mongodb collection:

#### Schema

```
const toDoSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    "name": {
        type: String
    },
    "todo": {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    "iv": {
        type: String
    },
    "secretToken": {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    "options": {
        type: Object,
        required: true
    }
}, { collection: config.collectionName });
```

#### the code what saves my documents

```js
        console.log('fast comparison before validation; wants',mem.options.protectedWithToken , 'already is',query.options.protectedWithToken)
        if (query.options.protectedWithToken === true || mem.options.protectedWithToken !== query.options.protectedWithToken) {

            // user didn't give token, and the document is protected
            if (!request.token) {
                // ......
            }

            // compare token values.
            
            if (request.token !== tokencontent) {
                // ....
            }
        }

        try {
            // save protectedWithToken to database

            console.log('before query.... = ...',query.options)

            query.options.protectedWithToken = mem.options.protectedWithToken
            console.log('after query.... = ...','database options',query.options, 'request options',mem.options)

            // save document
            updatequery = await query.save();
            console.log('saved:', updatequery.options.protectedWithToken)

            // declare response body
            result.status = 200
            result.id = query._id
            result.error = "document saved"
            
            // send response
            res.status(result.status).json(result)
```

and everything seems to work fine... except one little thing. It doesn't update the options.protectedWithToken to database.
The **'saved:', updatequery** returns options

#### what the program returns

I sent an `"options": { "protectedWithToken": true }` request.
With correct token, server didn't return an error.

```
fast comparison before validation; wants true already is false
before query.... = ... (db) { protectedWithToken: false }
after query.... = ... (db) { protectedWithToken: true } (request) { protectedWithToken: true }
saved: true
```

as you see, the **saved** is true, what means **true** should be saved in database. I looked the options in `cloud.mongodb.com`. they said options.protectedWithToken was false.

#### Update / Fix

Got it working by changing the `"options": {type: Object}` to `"options": {type: String}`, and stringifying the object to json before inserting to database.

Comment: Can you include a bit more relevant code, like where does `query` come from ? ( in "the code what saves my documents" section )

Comment: on start of the function I request the old data from mongodb, query is the response of that.
simplified, query = old data

Answer (score 0):

### Schema.Types.Mixed

One Problem I see in your Schema is the Type `Object` you are trying to set for `options`. As far as I see the documentation does not list `Object` as valid SchemaType. (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html)

I think what you are looking for is `Schema.Types.Mixed`, so like this

```
options : {
  type: Schema.Types.Mixed,
  required: true
}
```

or like one of these

```
options : Object
options : {}
options : mongoose.Mixed
```

Note (from the docs) :

> Since Mixed is a schema-less type, you can change the value to anything else you like, but Mongoose loses the ability to auto detect and save those changes. To tell Mongoose that the value of a Mixed type has changed, you need to call doc.markModified(path), passing the path to the Mixed type you just changed.

Maybe this already solves your problem

Comment: Didn't seem to work for me :(
Thank you though, maybe it'll help me in the future